# CONFIG_x86_x32 enabled but no binutils suppot kernel compilation error

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am trying to compile the Linux kernel and I am getting the error

CONFIG_x86_x32 enabled but no binutils support kernel compilation error

I have tried to change to the value of CONFIG_x86_x32 to "n" in the .config and the error persisted. After which I tried to sudo make clean and I got more errors, I hade to delete the entire virtual machine.

Unfortunately, as I have already mentioned I have deleted the files and cannot show the error, what should I have done?

it would be great if someone could help

'EDIT'

Now i have recompiled and this is what I'm getting

```
arch/x86/Makefile:155: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
Makefile:969: "Cannot use CONFIG_STACK_VALIDATION=y, please install libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel"
  CHK     include/config/kernel.release
CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_AUTO: Compiler does not support any known stack-protector
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  CC      arch/x86/purgatory/purgatory.o
/bin/sh: 1: gcc: not found
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:313: arch/x86/purgatory/purgatory.o] Error 127
make: *** [arch/x86/Makefile:263: archprepare] Error 2
```

now what does it really mean and what am is supposed to do to fix it

Thanks

Comment: As the error tell you: you doesn't have the 32-bit tools installed. `make clean` should not be run with sudo. But you should use `make mrproper` (after you copied your .config)

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, if I don't have 32-bit tools, won't it be easy to just disable 32-bit config and go-ahead with just 64bit or is it that it's necessary to keep it enabled

Comment: Configuration tools cannot test actual environment. And usually one select what he wants, and then he looks to install tools (just look binutils32 or something like than in your distribution). Building is complex (so testing is also difficult)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi, neither you nor OP seems to understand the meaning of the last X in the configuration option. Nevertheless, to OP: you have to export architecture or use one of predefined configuration prior to compile, like `make i386_defconfig; make -j4`.

Comment: @0andriy: maybe. In any case the help on that options: "You will need a recent binutils (2.22 or later) with elf32_x86_64 support enabled to compile a kernel with this option set.". But to answer OP: the feature is "EXPERIMENTAL". Are you sure you know what you are doing? Start with the configuration used by your distribution, check that it is working, then save configuration, and do changes, if it fails use oldconfiguration, until you get what do you want. Do not enable all things just because they seems cool: you make a slower kernel

Comment: "I have tried to change to the value of CONFIG_x86_x32 to "n" in the .config and the error persisted." Changes should be made via make menuconfig (or alternatives), not edited manually. In particular, setting options to "n" in the .config is not the correct way to disable them. (Also, options are in CAPITALS, but I assume that was just a typo.)